# Host multiple ssl domains in amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost, amazon-ebs

I need to install multiple ssl domains in my amazon ec2 instance.Amazon ec2 allows only one IP address so I decided to use load-balancers for each domains.

Scenario :

I host 4 domains in an ec2 instance.
1) example1.com
2) sub1.example2.com
3) sub2.example2.com
4) sub3.example2.com

I need separate ssl for all the above 4 sites. What I did is, configured webmin in ec2 and added the domains as virtual servers. I have installed the certificate in the loadbalancer itself. But now only the first domain example1.com is working fine and all others  doing nothing other than giving a blank page or errors based on the virtual host configuration files. I have used the route53 service for all the above domains. When I modify the vhosts, all the domains going to the default ssl site for example1.com. Please help !!
Thanks,

Comment: Assuming you are talking about website, which web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For all your information, I have resolved the issue and this is what I did :

1. Installed webmin.
2. Configured separate port for each domains.
3. Configured the Amazon ELB for each domain which will accept ssl and nonssl traffic and will forward to the corresponding port configured for the domain in the webmin.
4. Installed the SSL in the ELB itself.
5. Configured the back-end authentication with the server from the loadbalancer to the instances. (Use domain certificate as the back-end certificate)
6. Now everything works fine.

Hope this helps some one else....